# How to get status of buffering video and fix custom logo in video player in c# using VLC Plugin

Tags: c#, video, rtsp, vlc, buffering

I am developing a video player for Window based computer, which can play online streaming videos from any address e.g. rtsp://live.example.com/live/mystream

For this purpose I am using Plugin from VLC.

I have 2 questions:
1. How to get status of video player that whether it started buffering or not. If yes then show buffering as a progress.

1. VLC Plugin shows VLC's logo in middle of video plyer screen, when no video is getting played. How to replace that logo with my custom Logo:

Following is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.NetworkInformation;
using SikhPlayer;
using System.Windows;


namespace SikhPlayer
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {

            InitializeComponent();
                   }



        public void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            InitializeComponent();
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);

            //axVLCPlugin21.BringToFront();
            axVLCPlugin21.video.logo.file("http://localhost/logo.png");
            axVLCPlugin21.video.logo.opacity = 50;
            axVLCPlugin21.video.logo.Position = "center";
            axVLCPlugin21.video.logo.enable();


                axVLCPlugin21.AutoPlay = false;

        }

            private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           axVLCPlugin21.playlist.playItem(@"rtsp://ip.example.com:1935/live/mystream);


             axVLCPlugin21.Focus();
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            axVLCPlugin21.playlist.stop();
        }
    }
}
```

Please help me if you have answer to my questions.
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

1. To get status of buffering, add event name `axVLCPlugin21_MediaPlayerBuffering`

   It have 2 arguments: `object sender` , `AxAXVLC.DVLCEvents_MediaPlayerBufferingEvent e`

   You can use value of `e.cache` to get status of buffering. Its value ranges from 0 to 100. It's like percentage of video buffered.
2. If I am not wrong, I think you cant. But, you can add `picturebox` on the video plugin and use the status of buffering (as described above), or other event like `MediaPlayerPlaying`, etc. to make `picturebox visible` or invisible.